# How to handle the orthographic projection when auto-rotating screen?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, rotation, opengl-es-2.0

I have this method for performing the ortho projection:

```
void myGL::ApplyOrtho(float maxX, float maxY) const
{
float a = 1.0f / maxX;
float b = 1.0f / maxY;
float ortho[16] = {
    a, 0, 0, 0,
    0, b, 0, 0,
    0, 0, -1, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 1};

    GLint projectionUniform = glGetUniformLocation(m_simpleProgram, "Projection");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(projectionUniform, 1, 0, &ortho[0]);
  }
```

It works fine for iPad screen when I do this:

```
ApplyOrtho(2, 2*1024/768);
```

Here's my rendered image:

[image: arrow]

However, when I rotate to landscape, it looks like this:

[image: landscape arrow]

Now my assumption is this is because the `ApplyOrtho` matrix is setting a fixed projection and that projection does not rotate while the image is rotating within that projection, thus getting displayed fatter.

Incidentally, this is the rotation:

```
void myGL::ApplyRotation(float degrees) const
{
float radians = degrees * 3.14159f / 180.0f;
float s = std::sin(radians);
float c = std::cos(radians);
float zRotation[16] = {
    c, s, 0, 0,
    -s, c, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 1
};
GLint modelviewUniform = glGetUniformLocation(m_simpleProgram, "Modelview");
glUniformMatrix4fv(modelviewUniform, 1, 0, &zRotation[0]);
}
```

It is used right before drawing.

So I experimented and tried this at the same time I rotate:

```
 ApplyOrtho(2*1024/768, 2);
```

However this has no effect whatsoever, even though the rotation is definitely happening at the same time. My image remains "fat".

1. Is my interpretation of why the fatness is happening correct?
2. How to handle the orthographic projection when auto-rotating screen?

**UDPATE:** Also tried this on iPhone using the 2/3 dimensions of the screen (not iPhone 5) and using `ApplyOrtho(2,3)` and `ApplyOrtho(3,2)` but the "fat" triangle in landscape remains.

Also: the viewport is setup just once, before the first Ortho:

```
glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
```

Where width and height are the dimensions of the Portrait screen.

Comment: Could you show how are you setting up the viewport?

Comment: Are you doing the rotation by simply invoking ApplyRotation or is it a result of a device orientation change?

Comment: When the device orientation changes, the applied rotation is sents. There is no actual rotation occurring on the screen, it's all handled by The apply rotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the above discrepancies is that the orthographic projection is not matching the width and height ratio of the screen, thus the X and Y coordinates are not the same screen size. Making the orthographic ratio match the viewport ratio resolves this issue. As a result, when rotating, the image will remain exactly the same shape and size.